# unknown thread in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading

I'm a beginner in using Xcode and objective-c 
I always face this thread and I don't know why, neither how to fix it

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? That code is just the main implementation of any of templates.

Comment: What's your question again? To put it simply, that what will "start your app"...

Comment: when i run it, the program appears for a second then disappears and the following error show up <img src="http://www.4shared.com/download/25yA_edy/Screen_Shot_2013-07-16_at_1025.png?tsid=20130716-201531-d1d3c858">

Comment: What everyone is trying to say essentially is your error does not have anything specifically to do with what you are showing. You need to step through your application and finding out what lines are called before that error is thrown. As a newbie myself I used to think the same thing but then I found out that it is very misleading. Your error is something else.

Comment: I just posted this exact same piece of advice elsewhere, but I suggest you turn on the All Exceptions breakpoint. Here is a tutorial on how to do that: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: @nouf The image you posted is just *any* crash of your application. Please read the link that livingtech. It will help you figure out why your app is crashing

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're asking. To explain the code you've posted:

[`UIApplicationMain`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain) is:

> [a function that never returns which] instantiates the application
>   object from the principal class and instantiates the delegate (if any)
>   from the given class and sets the delegate for the application. It
>   also sets up the main event loop, including the application’s run
>   loop, and begins processing events. If the application’s Info.plist
>   file specifies a main nib file to be loaded, by including the
>   NSMainNibFile key and a valid nib file name for the value, this
>   function loads that nib file.

So in your case that passes on any command-line arguments that may have been received (which the OS may use for whatever purpose it desires — just pass them on), tells it just to use `UIApplication` as itself like every other application ever written and dictates that in your project the class named `AppDelegate` will be the application delegate.

The autorelease pool surrounds it because you're making a UIKit call and UIKit assumes an autorelease pool to be available.

Once that call has started the application's run loop and performed other basic startup tasks, it can start posting appropriate messages to your application delegate, such as `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.